# WPF RenderTargetBitmap memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I have a problem with memory leak in `RenderTargetBitmap` function.
Function runs many times. Memory is not released, and at some point there is an overflow.
I tried to free the memory with the help of `GC.Collect()`. I use:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

But it does not work. I've read that this is a problem with Net.Framework and the problem has disappeared with version 4.5.2. When compiling the new version of the framework remained a problem.
I have two PC with Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2013, where i can compiling my application. Once, on one of the computers memory leak was not, but after the restart it appeared again.